# Executing perl script from java

Tags: java, perl

I`m trying to execute a perl script with parameters from my java code.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl C:\\Users\\MIKE\\Desktop\\EvaluateCase\\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl -e data  -f A -a -x -s -m -2 -4 -u C:\\Users\\MIKE\\Desktop\\EvaluateCase\\CaseFromMike\\setting.xml");
```

The process exec failed and exit with value:255

The command works when I run in command prompt.
please help.

Comment: How do the perl script and your XML look like?

Comment: It depends on your script, but just in case try `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl", "C:\Users\MIKE\Desktop\EvaluateCase\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl", "-e", "data", "-f", "A", "-a", "-x", "-s", "-m", "-2", "-4", "-u", "C:\Users\MIKE\Desktop\EvaluateCase\CaseFromMike\setting.xml");`

Comment: Is your double quoted string being interpolated?  Maybe if you just change your command to use single quotes?  `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec('perl C:\....blahblahblah');`

Comment: @Miller what are you talking about? This is Java code, and Java doesn't even have string interpolation. Strings are always delimited by double quotes, single quotes are used for character literals.

Comment: @Demnogonis you could find Rouge.pl from http://research.microsoft.com/~cyl/download/ROUGE-1.5.5.tgz

Comment: @amon When I made the comment, I hadn't fixed the formatting of the OP's question yet, so the none of the escaped backslashes were showing:  `.exec("perl C:\Users\MIKE\Desktop\EvaluateCase\...`.  Yes, my Java is extremely rusty, but I believe \n will still translate to a return character in a "".  Either way, my question is negated because I can see now that all the blackslashes were in fact escaped.

Comment: @morgano I tried String [] cmd = {"perl", "C:\\Users\\I301671\\Dropbox\\Graduation Thesis\\Text Summary\\rouge\\EvaluateCase\\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl", "-h"}; Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); It still return exitvalue 255...not work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option -e of the script is also a path, use `C:\\Users\\MIKE\\Desktop\\EvaluateCase\\data` instead of just `data`:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
        "perl C:\\Users\\MIKE\\Desktop\\EvaluateCase\\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl " +
        "-e C:\\Users\\MIKE\\Desktop\\EvaluateCase\\data " +
        "-f A -a -x -s -m -2 -4 " +
        "-u C:\\Users\\MIKE\\Desktop\\EvaluateCase\\CaseFromMike\\setting.xml");
```